# gatling - extract cookie value string during test

Tags: scala, gatling

My tests run fine but now I need multiple sessions running at once.  I've tried getting the cookie value using `headerRegex("Set-Cookie", "HOME_SESSID=(.*)").saveAs("homeSessid")` but when I print this out its returning a value of `com.excilys.ebi.gatling.http.check.HttpMultipleCheckBuilder@6075598`

I have no idea where this is coming from.  My question is: what is going on?

Thanks.

edit:  forgot to mention that the value its returning is not a session id and no matter what I use for the cookie name I get the same value.

edit (solution):

1) In the first .exec: `.check( headerRegex("Set-Cookie", """HOME_SESSID=(.*dll/(\d+))""").saveAs("homeSessid") )`

2)  Then to retrieve `homeSessid` in later http requests I did, for example: 
`.post( session=>{session}.getAttribute("homeSessid").toString + "/some/relative/url" )`

Answer (score 3):

1) In the first .exec:

`.check( headerRegex("Set-Cookie", """HOME_SESSID=(.*dll/(\d+))""").saveAs("homeSessid") )`

2) Then to retrieve homeSessid in later http requests I did, for example:
`.post( session=>{session}.getAttribute("homeSessid").toString + "/some/relative/url" )`

Comment: 2) The following would be way more simple: .post("${homeSessid}/some/relative/url")

Comment: @Stephane.  Thanks and I tried this before but it wasn't being evaluated as the session value but just printing the string literal.  But it seems to be working now.  No idea why.  Thanks :)

Comment: I have another question- I have a "/" in the parameter list of the url that I don't want to be encoded to "%2F" because it represents a directory.  Is there any way I can force scala/gatling to not encode it?

Answer (score 2):

Please properly read the [Check documentation](https://github.com/excilys/gatling/wiki/Checks). Checks save data into the Session, so that's where you have to read. Here, you're just trying to print the extractor.

For example, after performing your check, you could add a [exec(function)](https://github.com/excilys/gatling/wiki/Session#wiki-functions), like:

```
.exec(session => {
  println(session("homeSessid").as[String]) // Gatling 2 API
  session
})
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer.  I'd like to use the session value in future http requests.  How would I go about this?

Comment: You really have to read the documentation, all the answers of the questions you're asking are there.

Comment: My check statement is working: `.check( headerRegex("Set-Cookie", "HOME_SESSID=(.*)").saveAs("homeSessid") )` and it OK when I execute it.  However when I add the exec function you described I'm getting a "type mismatch" error when it compiles:

`found   : java.lang.String("homeSessid")
required: com.excilys.ebi.gatling.core.Predef.Session`

Comment: My check statement: `.check( headerRegex("Set-Cookie", "HOME_SESSID=(.*)").saveAs("homeSessid") )`

When I try to print `homeSessid` out using `"$(homeSessid)"` it just prints the string literal